# Custom Sort Order Using System.Linq.Dynamic

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have records that are given a class that i need to order by.

The values are simple 0,1,2.  The problem is the client needs the records to appear in a order based on there class name not class value. The order should appear as seen below.

```
class (TBD)= 0
class (2/3)= 2 
class (1)= 1
```

`Using System.Linq.Dynamic` i have been able to pass columns and there direction into my `OrderBy()`. Is there a way to pass in a expression that would force the sort order to be

Ascending:
    class (TBD)= 0,
    class (2/3)= 2 ,
    class (1)= 1

Descending:
class (1)= 1,
class (2/3)= 2, 
class (TBD)= 0

I have tried
asc:

```
sort = "(Class = 0) desc, (Class = 2) desc, (Class = 1) desc";
```

desc:

```
sort = "(Class = 1) desc, (Class = 2) desc, (Class = 0) desc";
```

But i get `Operator '=' incompatible with operand types 'String' and 'Int32'` Before that i was using '==' and got a similar message.

```
 searchUniq = searchUniq.OrderBy(sort).Skip(skip).Take(25);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string is not a valid sort syntax for Dynamic Linq. Try:

```
sort = "iif(Class == 1, 0, iif(Class == 2, 1, 2))";
```

This uses the inline if expression available in Dynamic Linq (at least one flavor of it; see [here](http://dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net/Keywords/iif) for more documentation) to transform the Class values into something intuitively orderable. The vanilla SQL equivalent is to order by a case statement.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.